# Can you take advantage of implicit type variables with a class named `var`?

Tags: c#, var

I just found out that it is possible to use the keyword `var` as a class name:

```
public class var // no problem here
{
}
```

Now if I overload the implicit cast operator I can use my class in an interesting manner:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = 1; // var is of type MyApp.var
        }
    }

    public class var
    {
       public implicit operator var(int i)
       {
           return new var();
       }
    }
}
```

In such scenario, is it still possible to somehow make the compiler infer the types? [This blog entry](http://ericlippert.com/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords/) states that it is not possible (go to the paragraph starting with "Or, another example."), but maybe something changed since 2009?

Comment: No change. A change in how the compiler contextually interprets `var` would break backward compatibility. Not going to happen.

Comment: @walther It is a fun exercise.

Comment: @Petrichor, violating programming principles? I'm glad you find it fun :) The thing is it's not useful at all and people should avoid it and not try to hack the language and create really unexpected situations. I'm really surprised C# allows to name your class using a reserved keyword like this. It should be marked as a bug instead.

Comment: @walther [I am not alone](https://vimeo.com/68320506)... If the languages team made `var` a reserved keyword (even a contextual one), it would be a breaking change, which is just as bad (in production).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To make it short

It is not possible to use implicit variable declaration if you name a class `var`.

### Can't the C# design team just disallow naming classes like that to avoid confusing code?

No, because that might break some code written before the new meaning of `var` was introduced in the language. All legacy code with `var` as class names would not compile anymore. And I read lately that backwards compatibility is very important for the C# designer team.